# Javascript custom events object for another object?

Tags: javascript, events, object

I am making a custom events object so that I can inject custom events into another object, so far I have (simplified),

```
function Game() {

     new Events(["pause", "resume"], this);
};

function Events(events, obj) {

     // Event object for object
    obj.events = {};

    // For each event
    events.forEach(function(event) {

        // Attach event array to store callbacks
        this.events[event] = [];

    }, obj);

     // Fire event
     obj.fire = function(event) {

         ////////////
     };

     // Add event
     obj.on = function(event, callback) {

         ////////////
     };
};
```

My question is, is this the right way to do this? Is it considered ok to call `Event` from `Game` and add to `Game` from `Events`? It for some reason seems wrong to me, and I do not know why?

Is there any way that I should be structuring this code that I am not aware of?

(I do not want to add `Events` to `Game`'s prototype for the sole reason that `Game` has events and is not an extension of `Events`)

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, is this the right way to do this? Is it considered ok to call Event from Game and add to Game from Events?

Yes, it's perfectly fine. This is called the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). I don't see a reason for your feeling that it was wrong.

> Is there any way that I should be structuring this code that I am not aware of?

Don't use `new`. `Events` is not a constructor. A better and more descriptive signature might be

```
function makeEventEmitter(obj, events) {
```

Comment: So it's not the right way, but you do tell them the right way (don't need new)

Comment: @Juan: The pattern (which he felt wrong about) is OK, only he had syntactical issues. I mean, since he didn't store the result of the `new` call, it actually didn't really matter (other than being misleading and superflous)

Comment: Thank you for this @Bergi, I understand why I shouldn't now use `new` thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know where to begin trying to make some kind of system for custom events and ended up with this, so to know that it was ok apart from a few syntactical issues has pleased me! Thanks again.